# Guava: MutableGraph with nodeOrder that is inverse-insertion

Tags: java, guava, graph-theory

I want to create an object of type MutableGraph from Guava, like this:

```
MutableGraph<Integer> subgraph = GraphBuilder.undirected().nodeOrder(ElementOrder.insertion()).build();
```

When I use an iterator to get the nodes from the graph, the order is their insertion. I need to get them in reverse, so that I can retrieve that last added vertex with one call of

```
subgraph.nodes().iterator().next()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Graph` stores nodes in map under the hood, and [for `ElementOrder.insertion()` it's `LinkedHashMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/graph/ElementOrder.html#line.192). For `Graph#nodes()` `keySet()` of such map is used, so there's no better way to fetch last value other than iterating over all elements and returning the last one. Luckily there's a [helper method `Iterables#getLast(Iterable)` for that](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getLast-java.lang.Iterable-) in Guava:

```
Integer last = Iterables.getLast(subgraph.nodes());
```

If you want the code not to throw `NoSuchElementException` for empty graphs, use overload with default value, such as:

```
Integer last = Iterables.getLast(subgraph.nodes(), null);
```

(There're also [`Iterators` counterparts](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#getLast-java.util.Iterator-) of methods above.)

Comment: My concern was the runtime of this workaround, which getLast doesn't solve. Is it possible to make the LinkedHashMap use a DoubleLinkedList or to link the elements in the reverse order?

Comment: No, there's no way to customize that in `Graph` implementation. But if performance is a concern for you (i.e. you'll have hundreds of thousands elements in graph and you'll call `last` very often, otherwise it'd be a premature optimization), you can store last added element yourself in your code.

Comment: Ok, thank you. How do you know that ElementOrder can't be customized? I thought I missed how to do it, but I guess that's just not possible. Can you point me to the part in the wiki/documentation or did you just look up the sourcecode?

Comment: [Source code](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/graph/ElementOrder.html#line.192) - `ElementOrder` is a final class, has only private constructor, so your options are restricted to these [listed here](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/ElementOrder.Type.html).